# How to create smooth and fast movement

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I wrote a quick program to demonstrate my problem.

With the following code, when X is increased by 1 every update, the movement is smooth. However, it is also very slow, if I make X increase by 8 instead, it becomes more jagged. And the faster I try make it move, the less smooth it is.

Any ideas?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")

const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
x = 0;
setInterval(draw, 40)

function draw() {
  //Clear canvas
  context.fillStyle = "white"
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  //Draw black square
  context.fillStyle = "black"
  context.fillRect(x, 0, 50, 50)
  //Move square
  x += 1
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) which optimizes these types of animations. It usually runs at 60 fps.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
x = 0;

function draw() {
  //Clear canvas
  context.fillStyle = "white"
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  //Draw black square
  context.fillStyle = "black"
  context.fillRect(x, 0, 50, 50)
  //Move square
  x += 1
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Just curious, is there an equivalent of this in other languages?

Comment: Nitpicking, but rAF doesn't "optimizes" anything, it just calls what you passed to it, without any optimization. However, it is indeed the "optimal" timed loop for visual anims since it fires in sync with the screen refresh rate.

Answer (score 0):

1 st: you update your canvas every 40 ms, so you have 25 fps, what is not that much, when you try to achieve smooth animation. If you want 60 fps you should set the update interval to about 16 ms
Now the real problem, when you increase x by 8 or even higher value, your animated object jumps too far between single frames, what is causing the bad animation.

To solve your problem you should first set the update interval to 16 and check if it's enough speed for you. If it's not, try to lower the draw interval maybe up to 1 and maybe increase x by 2 or 4